# El Salvador visa exemption

Tags: visas, el-salvador

Many countries are visa exempt for El Salvador.  [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/) says up to 180 days; [another source](https://www.hinterlandtravel.com/usa/destinations/el-salvador) says ninety days and claims to be updated 10 December 2023.  Ninety days is also what many older sources say.

I haven’t found a Salvadoran source.  **What is the actual limit and source?**

Comment: Your 'Timatic' source seems to be a more general summery (lacking in details) that lumps different conditions togeather. Both the US state Department anf German goverment site state: initial entry of 90 days that can be extend for a further 90 days within the CA-4 region. Passport validaty 6 months when entering by air. The german site also says tha otherwise by land only valid on entry. The 'Timatic' states: 1) Nationals of USA for a maximum stay of 180 days. 2) Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid on arrival.

Comment: Yes, those are some of the "many older sources" I mentioned.  Timatic is supposed to be a reliable source, but there sure are a lot of sites that contradict it.  That's why I'm trying to find the "official" source.

Comment: Timatic may be a reliable source, but the summery offered by the Emirates site looks dubious.

Comment: Emirates did that?  I thought they were just relaying from Timatic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [El Salvador migration law, as found on the immigration department's website](https://www.migracion.gob.sv/servicios/legislacion-migratoria/), section C (tourists):

> #### Turista
>
> **Art.84.**- Para efectos migratorios se consideran turistas las personas que ingresen al país con fines recreativos, científicos, familiares o religiosos, que permanezcan en el territorio nacional hasta un máximo de noventa días calendario, sin propósito o ánimo de residir temporal o permanentemente, ni con fines laborales, académicos o comerciales.
>
> #### Prórroga de calidad de turista
>
> **Art.85.**- Podrá concederse prórroga al turista hasta por un período de noventa días calendario, siempre que se solicite con cinco días de anticipación a la expiración del período inicialmente otorgado y que
> demuestre razonablemente el propósito de su estadía en el país.
>
> En casos de desastre antropogénico, epidemias, fenómenos naturales, asunto humanitario, decreto de calamidad pública o bien por el interés superior de la niña, niño y adolescente, la Dirección General podrá otorgar una segunda prórroga de hasta noventa días calendario, siempre que se acredite en
> debida forma la respectiva circunstancia.
>
> Los requisitos y el procedimiento se establecerán en el Reglamento de la presente Ley.

So [my summary and partial translation, unofficial] tourists who engage in permitted activities may remain in El Salvador for up to a maximum of 90 calendar days. A 90-day extension (so, a total of 180 days) may be granted if it is applied for at least five days before the expiration of the original stay. A second extension (for a total of 270 days) will only be granted in the case of a disaster, epidemic, humanitarian need, or other similar special circumstances.

It [is apparently possible](https://www.migracion.gob.sv/servicios/prorroga-de-permanencia-para-turistas/) to apply for the extension by email, though, if granted, you will still have to visit the immigration office for stamping.

Comment: Your explanation does not contradict the text (Spanish is my second language).  So, I guess Timatic is telling the airlines to allow the 180 days because of the extension option.